# completing an observable after a series of returns

Tags: angular

I have an observable that runs/calls promises inside it one after the other and I want to complete it after forEach() is completed. Now as it happens, the .complete() is happening before the objects of the foreach are processed successfully.

```
 return new Observable<Person>(observer => {
 //get list of Person object from indexdb first
 // then loop over each
 this.service.getMembers().subscribe(people=>{
//process each person
 people.forEach(person=>{
 //promise one
  this.service.process1(person).then(processOne=>{
     // person object now have some values/properties added to it
   return processOne

    }).then(person=>{
      //person from processOne
      // do something to it now and emit it
      console.log(person); // i see correct data here for each person
      observer.next(person)


     })


    );

     observer.complete(); // doesn't work as it reaches here immediately

   });

 });
```

Comment: You need to put complete in then. But why do you create a new observable. Instead, pipe instead of subscribing and return that

Comment: can you add a little example @chrispbacon if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can `complete` with promise.all

```
    const promisses: Array<Promise> = [];
    people.forEach(person=>{

      promisses.push( 
           this.service.process1(person).then(processOne=>{
               return processOne    
           }).then(person=>{
               observer.next(person)
           });
      );
   });
   Promise.all(promisses).then(() => observer.complete())
```

### Cleaner solution

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

```
asyncForEach(people, async (person) => {

    const p1 = await this.service.process1(person);  
    const p2 = await this.service.process2(p1);


    observer.next(p2);
});

observer.complete();
```